# How can i use arcgis server services in arcgis viewer for silverlight?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-silverlight-api

I want to create  a webgis using arcgis viewer for silverlight. i install arcgi viewer . when i want to connect to arcgis server service , the application show the error" unable to connect to "http://server name/ArcGIS/services/test". I copied clientaccesspolicy.xml into C:\inetpub\wwwroot but the application show same error .
i tried "http://server name:8399/arcgis/services/test" but it doesn't solve my problem.
 i couldn't find any good help for this reason . what's my problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer these questions by editing your Question to include the additional information.

Open a browser.

1. Can you hit  *servername/ArcGIS/rest/services/* ?
2. Can you hit  *servername:8399/ArcGIS/rest/services/* ?
3. Can you hit  *servername/ArcGIS/rest/services/yourmapservice/mapserver* ?
4. Can you confirm the error is happening when your browsing to your ArcGIS Server, or when you add a particular map service from that ArcGIS Server?
5. Can you confirm your clientaccesspolicy.xml looks similar to [this](http://services.arcgisonline.com/clientaccesspolicy.xml)?

Also from the [Esri Help:](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/silverlight-viewer/concepts/index.html#/Frequently_asked_questions/01770000000r000000/)

> Use the InitializationFailure event on the layer to determine if an
>   error is occurring, and interrogate the error message. View the HTTP
>   request and response using a standard tool for interrogating HTTP
>   communication such as Fiddler, Silverlight Spy, FireBug (FireFox
>   add-on), and so on.

In particular, would be interesting to see the HTTP logs to identify whats causing the issue.

Comment: i can't connect to  :                   servername/ArcGIS/rest/services/   servername:8399/ArcGIS/rest/services/                          servername/ArcGIS/rest/services/yourmapservice/mapserver

Comment: If u cant hit them in a browser, then its not going to work.  Please elaborate more by putting more info in your original Q.